# Is there a way to monitor remotly multiple windows server for hardware performance?

Tags: windows, monitoring, windows-server-2016, performance-monitoring

We have 5 server installed as VM with "Windows Server 2016" on VMWware. These servers are configured as RDS, means multiple users are working on it. Users which are connected on these servers are running heavy workload. Sometimes it happens, that the server is crashing. Means it has a black screen, so no possibility to access over RDP. However access on filesystem over UNC is still possible.

I would like to ask about a possiblity to real time monitor these servers. I was thinking about installing a server, which has the service installed and is doing remote monitoring these 5 servers in realtime.

Is there any role build in Windows Server to use it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use windows exporter service to expose your metrics + prometheus to scrape those metrics and then finally visualize it using grafana.

Im currently running this setup and i am pretty satisfied.

[Grafana dashboard example](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/14694)